# subtract a "char" in assembly code at&t syntax

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to figure out a assembly example, which is at&t syntax. The code is to find the lowercase of string. In line 26 and 28, what does it mean by the distance? I know $'a' here is something like ascii, but what is the distance? and why dont we just compare $bl with 'a' and 'z' to see if it's lowcase?

```
1 .data
2 x: .string "c92jemc82ne<824j8vcm92jq3.,.u"
3 counts:
4   .rept 26
5   .byte 0
6   .endr
7 .text
8 .globl _start
9 _start:
10   # EAX will always point to the current character to be tallied
11   movl $x, %eax
12 top:
13   # need to zero out all of EBX for later use (see subl)
14   movl $0, %ebx
15   # get the character to be tallied
16   movb (%eax), %bl
17   # check for end of string
18   cmpb $0, %bl
19   jz done
20   # check to see if in range ’a’-’z’
21   cmpb $’a’, %bl
22   js nextchar
23   cmpb $’z’+1, %bl
24   jge nextchar
25   # find distance past counts where we will increment
26   subl $’a’,%ebx
27   # add that distance to counts to get address of place to increment
28   addl $counts, %ebx
29   # now increment
30   incb (%ebx)
31   # OK, ready to go to the next character in the string
32 nextchar:
33   addl $1, %eax
34   jmp top
35 done: movl %edx, %edx`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know $'a' here is something like ascii, but what is the distance?

Not "something like", it **is** ASCII code for `'a'`. By distance here they mean how far it is from `a` ASCII code, that is, substracting its code from 'a' code.

> why dont we just compare $bl with 'a' and 'z' to see if it's lowcase?

They're already doing that:

```
20   # check to see if in range ’a’-’z’
21   cmpb $’a’, %bl
22   js nextchar
23   cmpb $’z’+1, %bl
24   jge nextchar
```

Comment: Yes, i know they compare $bl with 'a' and 'z', but why do we still need to find the distance?

Comment: Because that code is not only to find if a string is lowercase.